# Infinite loop somewhere in a CYOA game

Tags: android

Why is the code breaking?

Intro: trying to make a "Choose Your Own Adventure" game.

Layout is composed by: 
bPage = button saying what page the user is on. Click to manually change page (not implemented yet)
bOne: go through first path
bTwo: go through second path
tvPageTitle: page title, at the top
mainText: main text body (story explained here)

there's also a splash screen, which works perfectly, but when you click on "start", it loads this layout, which hangs (possible infinite loop)

Can someone tell me why? Tried to put as many comments as I could, so it should be self explanatory

Please ask as many questions as you want :)

```
package com.assignement.cyoa;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Remember extends Activity {

        // Declaring variables
        TextView mainText; 
        int page = 1;
        MediaPlayer pageflip;
        Boolean gameOver = false;
        int currentPage = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.remember);

            // Enable manual scrolling text
            mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            mainText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

            // Enable sound when choosing path
            pageflip = MediaPlayer.create(Remember.this, R.raw.pageflip);

            //TODO: customise story to insert player name. Remember to import method 
            //EditText userName = LoginActivity.userName;

            // Link XML Views with Java 
            final TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            final TextView tvPageTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPageTitle); 
            final Button bOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOne);
            final Button bTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwo);
            final Button bPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPage);

            // Array creation
            final String[] storyText = new String[22];
            final String[] pageTitle = new String[22];
            final CharSequence[] pathA = new CharSequence[22];
            final CharSequence[] pathB = new CharSequence[22];

            ///// MAIN TEXT AND POSSIBLE PATHS ARRAYS \\\\\

            // Page 0 - Error
            storyText[0] = "Path broken";
            pageTitle[0] = "Path broken";
            pathA[0]= "Path broken";
            pathB[0]= "Path broken";


            // Page 1
            storyText[1] = "\tYou lift open your eyes. All you can see is a bright light. You get up and take a look around you. You are in a very tight room, with no windows and one door. Everything is painted in white. Beside the door is a small walkie talkie which looks brand new.\n\tYou begin to think, where are you? Who are you? You steady yourself and stumble towards the door. You tightly grab the knob and begin to twist it open. It's locked. Damn. You take another spin around the place. You don't know where you are, you don't know who you are, and you are trapped inside this small room. You pace slowly around the room with your mind thinking intensely on what to do.\n\tYou pick up the walkie talkie. You press the button for the microphone and speak.\n\t''Hello? Is anyone there?''\n\tThe room remains silent until a voice springs out of the device.\n\t''Ahh yes, hello!'' The voice is very high pitched, seemingly happy, yet, sinister. ''Do you remember who you are?''\n\tYou think once more, trying to remember who you are, but nothing manages to spring up.\n\t''Hello? Do you remember-''\n\t''No,'' you answer unhappily. ''I don't''\n\tSilence fills the room once more, but the voice comes back.\n\t''Good, this should make things much more interesting.''\n\tYou don't know whether you should be scared or happy. Questions pop up in your mind.";
            pageTitle[1] = "Your New Home";
            pathA[1]= "You brush it off and go anyway";
            pathB[1]= "Decide it's not worth it and leave";

            // Page 2
            storyText[2] = "Test";
            pageTitle[2] = "Not worth it";
            pathA[2]= "Go back";
            pathB[2]= "";

            // Page 3
            storyText[3] = "Test";
            pageTitle[3] = "You brush it off";
            pathA[3]= "Go upstairs and explore the mysterious shadow";
            pathB[3]= "Go to the kitchen to start unpacking";

            // Page 4
            storyText[4] = "Test";
            pageTitle[4] = "You go upstairs";
            pathA[4]= "Check it out";
            pathB[4]= "Go to the kitchen to start unpacking";

            // Page 5 - End
            storyText[5] = "Test";
            pageTitle[5] = "Checking it out";
            pathA[5]= "Try Again";
            pathB[5]= "";

            // Page 6
            storyText[6] = "Test";
            pageTitle[6] = "The Kitchen";
            pathA[6]= "It's probably just a cat, continue unpacking";
            pathB[6]= "Check it out";

            // Page 7
            storyText[7] = "Test";
            pageTitle[7] = "Unpacking";
            pathA[7]= "Check out the basement";
            pathB[7]= "";

            // Page 8
            storyText[8] = "Test";
            pageTitle[8] = "Checking it out";
            pathA[8]= "Check out the basement";
            pathB[8]= "";

            // Page 9
            storyText[9] = "Test";
            pageTitle[9] = "The Basement";
            pathA[9]= "Forget the light! Get out of here!";
            pathB[9]= "Turn the light on anyways";

            // Page 10 - End
            storyText[10] = "Test";
            pageTitle[10] = "Leaving";
            pathA[10]= "Try Again";
            pathB[10]= "";

            // Page 11
            storyText[11] = "Test";
            pageTitle[11] = "Lights on";
            pathA[11]= "Chase the mysterious shadow";
            pathB[11]= "Scream and run upstairs";

            // Page 12
            storyText[12] = "Test";
            pageTitle[12] = "The Mysterious Shadow";
            pathA[12]= "News report";
            pathB[12]= "";

            // Page 13 - END
            storyText[13] = "Test";
            pageTitle[13] = "News Report";
            pathA[13]= "Try Again";
            pathB[13]= "";

            // Page 14
            storyText[14] = "Test";
            pageTitle[14] = "Upstairs";
            pathA[14]= "Just stay where you are";
            pathB[14]= "Answer the door";

            // Page 15 - End
            storyText[15] = "Test";
            pageTitle[15] = "Stay where you are";
            pathA[15]= "Try Again";
            pathB[15]= "";

            // Page 16
            storyText[16] = "Test";
            pageTitle[16] = "The Door";
            pathA[16]= "Go to the Attic";
            pathB[16]= "";

            // Page 17
            storyText[17] = "Test";
            pageTitle[17] = "The Attic";
            pathA[17]= "Leave it alone";
            pathB[17]= "Play with the Ouija Board";

            // Page 18
            storyText[18] = "Test";
            pageTitle[18] = "Left Alone";
            pathA[18]= "Jump out of the window";
            pathB[18]= "Accept your fate";

            // Page 19
            storyText[19] = "Test";
            pageTitle[19] = "The Ouija Board";
            pathA[19]= "Jump out of the window";
            pathB[19]= "Accept your fate";

            // Page 20 - End
            storyText[20] = "Test";
            pageTitle[20] = "Out the Window";
            pathA[20]= "Try Again";
            pathB[20]= "";

            // Page 21 - End
            storyText[21] = "Test";
            pageTitle[21] = "Fate Accepted";
            pathA[21]= "Try Again";
            pathB[21]= "";

            // Loop until Game Over
            do {

                // Populate fields and play page flip sound
                mainText.setText(storyText[page]);
                tvPageTitle.setText(pageTitle[page]);
                bOne.setText(pathA[page]);
                bTwo.setText(pathB[page]);
                bPage.setText("" + page);
                pageflip.start();

                currentPage = page;

                // Hide button 2 if it doesn't have a possible option
                if (pathB[page] == "")
                    bTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                else
                    bTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                /*
                TODO: Enable debug. Manually change page when clicking on the page button
                bPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ???
                    }
                });
                */

                // Operate first path
                bOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch (currentPage) {
                            case 1: page = 3;
                            break;
                            case  2: page = 1;
                            break;
                            case  3: page = 4;
                            break;
                            case  4: page = 5;
                            break;
                            case  5: page = 1;
                            break;
                            case  6: page = 7;
                            break;
                            case  7: page = 9;
                            break;
                            case  8: page = 9;
                            break;
                            case  9: page = 10;
                            break;
                            case  10: page = 1;
                            break;
                            case  11: page = 12;
                            break;
                            case  12: page = 13;
                            break;
                            case  13: page = 1;
                            break;
                            case  14: page = 15;
                            break;
                            case  15: page = 1;
                            break;
                            case  16: page = 17;
                            break;
                            case  17: page = 18;
                            break;
                            case  18: page = 20;
                            break;
                            case  19: page = 20;
                            break;
                            case  20: page = 1;
                            break;
                            case  21: page = 1;
                            break;
                            default: page = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Operate second path
                bTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch (currentPage) {
                        case  1: page = 2;
                        break;
                        case  2: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  3: page = 6;
                        break;
                        case  4: page = 6;
                        break;
                        case  5: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  6: page = 8;
                        break;
                        case  7: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  8: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  9: page = 11;
                        break;
                        case  10: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  11: page = 14;
                        break;
                        case  12: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  13: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  14: page = 16;
                        break;
                        case  15: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  16: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  17: page = 19;
                        break;
                        case  18: page = 21;
                        break;
                        case  19: page = 21;
                        break;
                        case  20: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  21: page = 0;
                        break;
                        default: page = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });

            } while (gameOver == false);
            //TODO: Game Over screen
        }
    }
```

EDIT2: adopted new suggestion, made according changes. now layout loads, but clicking a button makes the app crash

```
package com.assignement.cyoa;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Remember extends Activity {

        // Declaring variables
        int page;
        int currentPage;

        MediaPlayer pageflip;

        TextView mainText;
        TextView tvPageTitle;   

        Button bOne;
        Button bTwo;
        Button bPage; 

        // Array creation
        String[] storyText = new String[22];
        String[] pageTitle = new String[22];
        CharSequence[] pathA = new CharSequence[22];
        CharSequence[] pathB = new CharSequence[22];

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.remember);

            // Link XML Views with Java 
            TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            TextView tvPageTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPageTitle);   
            Button bOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOne);
            Button bTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwo);
            Button bPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPage);

            // Enable manual scrolling text
            mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            mainText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

            // Enable sound when choosing path
            pageflip = MediaPlayer.create(Remember.this, R.raw.pageflip);

            ///// MAIN TEXT AND POSSIBLE PATHS ARRAYS \\\\\

            // Page 0 - Error
            storyText[0] = "Path broken";
            pageTitle[0] = "Path broken";
            pathA[0]= "Path broken";
            pathB[0]= "Path broken";

            // Page 1
            storyText[1] = "\tYou lift open your eyes. All you can see is a bright light. You get up and take a look around you. You are in a very tight room, with no windows and one door. Everything is painted in white. Beside the door is a small walkie talkie which looks brand new.\n\tYou begin to think, where are you? Who are you? You steady yourself and stumble towards the door. You tightly grab the knob and begin to twist it open. It's locked. Damn. You take another spin around the place. You don't know where you are, you don't know who you are, and you are trapped inside this small room. You pace slowly around the room with your mind thinking intensely on what to do.\n\tYou pick up the walkie talkie. You press the button for the microphone and speak.\n\t''Hello? Is anyone there?''\n\tThe room remains silent until a voice springs out of the device.\n\t''Ahh yes, hello!'' The voice is very high pitched, seemingly happy, yet, sinister. ''Do you remember who you are?''\n\tYou think once more, trying to remember who you are, but nothing manages to spring up.\n\t''Hello? Do you remember-''\n\t''No,'' you answer unhappily. ''I don't''\n\tSilence fills the room once more, but the voice comes back.\n\t''Good, this should make things much more interesting.''\n\tYou don't know whether you should be scared or happy. Questions pop up in your mind.";
            pageTitle[1] = "Your New Home";
            pathA[1]= "You brush it off and go anyway";
            pathB[1]= "Decide it's not worth it and leave";

            // Page 2
            storyText[2] = "Test";
            pageTitle[2] = "Not worth it";
            pathA[2]= "Go back";
            pathB[2]= "";

            // Page 3
            storyText[3] = "Test";
            pageTitle[3] = "You brush it off";
            pathA[3]= "Go upstairs and explore the mysterious shadow";
            pathB[3]= "Go to the kitchen to start unpacking";

            // Page 4
            storyText[4] = "Test";
            pageTitle[4] = "You go upstairs";
            pathA[4]= "Check it out";
            pathB[4]= "Go to the kitchen to start unpacking";

            // Page 5 - End
            storyText[5] = "Test";
            pageTitle[5] = "Checking it out";
            pathA[5]= "Try Again";
            pathB[5]= "";

            // Page 6
            storyText[6] = "Test";
            pageTitle[6] = "The Kitchen";
            pathA[6]= "It's probably just a cat, continue unpacking";
            pathB[6]= "Check it out";

            // Page 7
            storyText[7] = "Test";
            pageTitle[7] = "Unpacking";
            pathA[7]= "Check out the basement";
            pathB[7]= "";

            // Page 8
            storyText[8] = "Test";
            pageTitle[8] = "Checking it out";
            pathA[8]= "Check out the basement";
            pathB[8]= "";

            // Page 9
            storyText[9] = "Test";
            pageTitle[9] = "The Basement";
            pathA[9]= "Forget the light! Get out of here!";
            pathB[9]= "Turn the light on anyways";

            // Page 10 - End
            storyText[10] = "Test";
            pageTitle[10] = "Leaving";
            pathA[10]= "Try Again";
            pathB[10]= "";

            // Page 11
            storyText[11] = "Test";
            pageTitle[11] = "Lights on";
            pathA[11]= "Chase the mysterious shadow";
            pathB[11]= "Scream and run upstairs";

            // Page 12
            storyText[12] = "Test";
            pageTitle[12] = "The Mysterious Shadow";
            pathA[12]= "News report";
            pathB[12]= "";

            // Page 13 - END
            storyText[13] = "Test";
            pageTitle[13] = "News Report";
            pathA[13]= "Try Again";
            pathB[13]= "";

            // Page 14
            storyText[14] = "Test";
            pageTitle[14] = "Upstairs";
            pathA[14]= "Just stay where you are";
            pathB[14]= "Answer the door";

            // Page 15 - End
            storyText[15] = "Test";
            pageTitle[15] = "Stay where you are";
            pathA[15]= "Try Again";
            pathB[15]= "";

            // Page 16
            storyText[16] = "Test";
            pageTitle[16] = "The Door";
            pathA[16]= "Go to the Attic";
            pathB[16]= "";

            // Page 17
            storyText[17] = "Test";
            pageTitle[17] = "The Attic";
            pathA[17]= "Leave it alone";
            pathB[17]= "Play with the Ouija Board";

            // Page 18
            storyText[18] = "Test";
            pageTitle[18] = "Left Alone";
            pathA[18]= "Jump out of the window";
            pathB[18]= "Accept your fate";

            // Page 19
            storyText[19] = "Test";
            pageTitle[19] = "The Ouija Board";
            pathA[19]= "Jump out of the window";
            pathB[19]= "Accept your fate";

            // Page 20 - End
            storyText[20] = "Test";
            pageTitle[20] = "Out the Window";
            pathA[20]= "Try Again";
            pathB[20]= "";

            // Page 21 - End
            storyText[21] = "Test";
            pageTitle[21] = "Fate Accepted";
            pathA[21]= "Try Again";
            pathB[21]= "";

                /*
                TODO: Enable debug. Manually change page when clicking on the page button
                bPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ???
                    }
                });
                */

            // Populate fields according to first page
            page = 1;
            currentPage = page;

            mainText.setText(storyText[page]);
            tvPageTitle.setText(pageTitle[page]);
            bOne.setText(pathA[page]);
            bTwo.setText(pathB[page]);
            bPage.setText("" + page);

            pageflip.start();


             // Hide button 2 if it doesn't have a possible option
             if (pathB[page] == "")
                 bTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              else
                 bTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Operate first path
            bOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (currentPage) {
                        case 1: page = 3;
                        break;
                        case  2: page = 1;
                        break;
                        case  3: page = 4;
                        break;
                        case  4: page = 5;
                        break;
                        case  5: page = 1;
                        break;
                        case  6: page = 7;
                        break;
                        case  7: page = 9;
                        break;
                        case  8: page = 9;
                        break;
                        case  9: page = 10;
                        break;
                        case  10: page = 1;
                        break;
                        case  11: page = 12;
                        break;
                        case  12: page = 13;
                        break;
                        case  13: page = 1;
                        break;
                        case  14: page = 15;
                        break;
                        case  15: page = 1;
                        break;
                        case  16: page = 17;
                        break;
                        case  17: page = 18;
                        break;
                        case  18: page = 20;
                        break;
                        case  19: page = 20;
                        break;
                        case  20: page = 1;
                        break;
                        case  21: page = 1;
                        break;
                        default: page = 0;
                    }
                    setPage(page);
                }
            });

            // Operate second path
            bTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (currentPage) {
                        case  1: page = 2;
                        break;
                        case  2: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  3: page = 6;
                        break;
                        case  4: page = 6;
                        break;
                        case  5: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  6: page = 8;
                        break;
                        case  7: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  8: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  9: page = 11;
                        break;
                        case  10: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  11: page = 14;
                        break;
                        case  12: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  13: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  14: page = 16;
                        break;
                        case  15: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  16: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  17: page = 19;
                        break;
                        case  18: page = 21;
                        break;
                        case  19: page = 21;
                        break;
                        case  20: page = 0;
                        break;
                        case  21: page = 0;
                        break;
                        default: page = 0;
                        }

                    }
            });
        }

        private void setPage(int curPage)
        {
            // Populate fields and play page flip sound
            page = curPage;
            mainText.setText(storyText[page]);
            tvPageTitle.setText(pageTitle[page]);
            bOne.setText(pathA[page]);
            bTwo.setText(pathB[page]);
            bPage.setText("" + page);
            pageflip.start();

            currentPage = page;

             // Hide button 2 if it doesn't have a possible option
             if (pathB[page] == "")
                 bTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              else
                 bTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is definitely an infinite `loop`. You have

```
 } while (gameOver == false);
```

but you never make `gameOver == true`. But I would reconsider your design. Instead of having this in a `loop`, it looks like you could have a function that sets the text of your `TextView`s and do that work and call that from your `onClick`s passing the function the `int` that it needs to select the right pages, etc... There is no reason to continually set your `OnClickListener`s in a `loop`. It can be done once in `onCreate()`.

**Edit**

```
    private void setPage(int curPage)
    {
        page = curPage;
        mainText.setText(storyText[page]);
        tvPageTitle.setText(pageTitle[page]);
        bOne.setText(pathA[page]);
        bTwo.setText(pathB[page]);
        bPage.setText("" + page);
        pageflip.start();

        currentPage = page;

         // Hide button 2 if it doesn't have a possible option
         if (pathB[page] == "")
             bTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          else
             bTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

then in your `onClick()` call the function

```
 bOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (currentPage) {
     case 1: page = 3;
     break;
     case  2: page = 1;
     break;
     case  3: page = 4;
     break;
     ...
   }
     setPage(page);
```

Declare your variables as member variables before (`onCreate()`) but initialize them in `onCreate()`

```
public class Remember extends Activity {
    TextView mainText;
    TextView tvPageTitle;   
    Button bOne;
    Button bTwo;
    Button bPage; 

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remember);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
        tvPageTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPageTitle);   
        bOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOne);
        bTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwo);
        bPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPage);
```

You can't initialize your `View`s before you have inflated the `layout` with `setContentView()`

You have

```
TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
```

inside `onCreate()`. Change that to

```
mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
```

remove the `TextView` otherwise you are creating a local variable and your member variables don't have a value so you will get `NPE`. Do the same with all of your `View`s.

Comment: Probably the loop is there, because if you set the "do-while" loop to "gameOver == true", it doesnt loop, so everything works fine, although the buttons dont work (obviously)

My knowledge is still very low on java. May I ask how can I create a new method and call if with the onClick?

Comment: See my edit. May need some tweaking because I'm not going to write the whole program but that should give you an idea. Ask if you don't understand something about it.

Comment: changed, please check my first post. Thanks!

Comment: See my edit again. Its easier if you declare your `View`s as member variables then initialize them in `onCreate()` unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure without knowing what the logcat says. Please post that also. And see my edit again. You are still declaring the `View`s in `onCreate()`. Declare them before then initialize them (give them the value) inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: I just added another edit to the bottom of my answer. Your `View`s are `null` because you are declaring local variables. That should solve your problem.

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much! The culprit was exactly that: duplicating the Views assignment inside and outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

If i followed your code correctly, it seems you start on page 1, and then just loop.
Your seem to be relying on break; to exit the do-while, but you are just setting the onclicklistener. Are you actually clicking anything?  bOne or bTwo i mean. If you dont click them, infinite loop.

Comment: yes, in theory it should go like this: 1) open layout, populate all fields depending on the page (read arrays). 2) wait for button press (2 options available). 3) on button press, change page according to what button was pressed and on what page it currently is on

Comment: You shouldnt need a loop for this. I'd just call a method that would set mainText.setText(storyText[page]);
                tvPageTitle.setText(pageTitle[page]);
                bOne.setText(pathA[page]);
                bTwo.setText(pathB[page]);
                bPage.setText("" + page);
                pageflip.start(); fro

Comment: from whitin the onlclick listeners. That way you build your game in a state machine kind of way. I think you dont need a loop, because its the buttons that trigger the next step.